# Error in setup_class method - missing 1 required positional arguement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Test:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls, the_default):
        ----

    def test(self, the_default):
        -----------

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls, the_default):
        -------------
```

Expected output - Test should run.

Current output - I am getting error TypeError: setup_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'the_default'

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `the_default` is, but any testing I've done never included it in the method/function signature.

It appears your testing framework doesn't expect it to be there, so remove it from your setup, test, and tear down functions.